# Task Killer Apps vs. SupportFragmentManager Backstack

Tags: android, android-fragments

I face the following very annoying problem:

I'm using the *Google Compatibility Library* in order to future-proof my apps.
Now... I'm keeping track of my `backstack`:

1) Launch App.

2) User Interaction A -> Fragment gets added to UI/ Back Stack.

```
--- Backstack Size: 1 ---
```

3) User "backgrounds" the app.

**4) User kills the App with a Taskkiller / or the app gets killed by the android system**

5) Launch app again. Full Restart of the application (`Application.onCreate()`) presented to the User.

6) User Interaction A -> Fragment gets added to UI/ Back Stack.

```
--- Backstack Size: 2 ---
```

**At this point I would want to have a backstack size of 1**.

If the user presses `back` now, the app takes him back to some former state, which doesn't make sense anymore, because the app presented a fresh start.

Any Idea on How to do this??

Thx

Answer (score 0):

Although your application has indeed been killed, there is not technically a 'full restart' when you try to launch it again. This is certainly not the way Android would want you to consider the situation.

When you background your app, Android will save the state of the fragments that have been added to the fragment manager (as well as the state of which activities are open, and their view state). When you relaunch your app after getting killed, Android will give you back all of this state and so you should be able to resume from exactly where you left off. This means you should consider that 'User Interaction A' has already happened and really you are at step 2) again. As you have noticed, the backstack is preserved; this is because the fragment transactions you have performed are also preserved.

The problem is of course, that we don't always write our apps in a way to match this behaviour. If your app presents a 'fresh start' after being killed whilst backgrounded, then arguably it is not really following the Android approach (assuming there is some user state worth saving).

I think you should try as best you can to resume as at step 2); it will likely be (marginally!) easier than trying to prevent Android from saving this state.